# Support for object literal routing parameters in Angular UI Router

Tags: angular-ui-router

I've been using Angular UI Router with a current project and have introduced some compound form inputs that I'd like to use as parameters in URL building for my routes. Essentially, the models I would like to parameterize are object literals, and I'm curious to know if ui-router has any ability to represent these as URL parameters.

In other parts of our application we have represented compound parameters with dot notation, e.g. `?field1.a=&field1.b=&field1.c`, and I know some PHP frameworks make use of an array notation, e.g. `?field1[a]=field1[b]=field1[c]` for representing multiple form fields associated with a single model.

From what I can tell, angular ui-router doesn't support similar. We are using v0.2.8, and at ~L131 there is a normalization function that will coerce object literals to their `[object Object]` string representation. It is this value that appears in URLs built with this kind of parameter, e.g. `?field1=[object Object]`.

I have considered lumping all the relevant fields together as a single parameter with a JSON string value as a workaround, e.g. `?filter={"field1":{}, "field2":{}, ...}`, but wanted to check in to see if anyone has a better solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have good timing.  Typed parameter support was just merged into ui-router master.  It isn't part of the 0.2.10 release, but should be part of 0.3.0 release, which is a few weeks away.  If you build your own copy of bleeding-edge master and use this functionality now, please submit feedback to the ui-router project!

Here's the pull request that got merged with typed parameter support: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/pull/1032

Read the docs regarding Type in https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/blob/master/src/urlMatcherFactory.js#L583

Comment: High-five @Chris T. If you're looking to encode full objects in a query parameter, I would consider combining the above with something like [Rison](https://github.com/Nanonid/rison).

Comment: This looks like a big improvement over the current system, @Chris T. I will try this out for sure, thanks!